# Postgres update error using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework

I'm having problems updating an entity that has a many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework.

This is my entity that links many Profiles to SubMenus.

```
public class ProfilesSubMenus : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid ProfileId { get; private set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Profile? Profile { get; private set; }
    public Guid SubMenuId { get; private set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public SubMenu? SubMenu { get; private set; }
}
```

This is my `Profile` entity:

```
public class Profile : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<User>? Users { get; private set; }
    public List<ProfilesSubMenus>? ProfilesSubMenus { get; private set; }
}
```

This is my `SubMenu` entity:

```
public class SubMenu : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid MenuId { get; private set; }
    public Menu Menu { get; private set; }
    public string Icon { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Path { get; private set; }
    public List<ProfilesSubMenus>? ProfilesSubMenus { get; private set; }
}
```

And this is my update method:

```
public async Task<ProfileOutput> Handle(UpdateProfileInput input)
{
        var profile = await _profileRepository.GetById(input.Id);
        profile!.Update(input.Name);
        var profilesSubMenus =
            input.ProfilesSubMenus.Select(x => new ProfilesSubMenus(x.SubMenuId,    profile!.Id)).ToList();
        profile.AddProfilesSubMenus(profilesSubMenus);
        await _unitOfWork.Commit();

        return ProfileOutput.FromOutput(profile);
}
```

It searches the database for a profile based on an id received by the input, then calls an update method existing in the profile class.

```
public void Update(string name)
{
    Name = name;
    UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Validate();
}
```

Right after it maps subMenus received by the input to a subMenu entity, and calls the method adding these subMenus to the profile.

```
public void AddProfilesSubMenus(List<ProfilesSubMenus> profilesSubMenus)
{
    if (profilesSubMenus != null && profilesSubMenus.Count < 0)
        throw new EntityValidationException("Sub menus is required");

    ProfilesSubMenus = profilesSubMenus;
}
```

And after this entire process, this is the object created to save.

```
{
  "id": "d8aa0ec8-9e0f-4d68-b784-871e00949248",
  "name": "Administrador1",
  "profilesSubMenus": [
    {
      "subMenuId": "9a6f7ab0-9a42-4ba7-a69c-270983722517",
      "profileId": "d8aa0ec8-9e0f-4d68-b784-871e00949248"
    },
    {
      "subMenuId": "a5dfbaae-9481-4639-a763-328c682f63ce",
      "profileId": "d8aa0ec8-9e0f-4d68-b784-871e00949248"
    },
    {
      "subMenuId": "f6efd7f1-9887-4a85-a163-da546bf23c58",
      "profileId": "d8aa0ec8-9e0f-4d68-b784-871e00949248"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when will he commit to the bank

```
public async Task Commit()
{
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I get an error

> The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded